# urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl-certificate

I installed seaborn Python package and tried running the [first tutorial](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/introduction.html) and it generated a stream of errors.

What am I doing wrong? I copied&pasted the tutorial code into a file called seaborn1.py and clicked run and I got this:

```
/Users/apple/python/python-venv/bin/python3.12 /Users/apple/python/project1/seaborn1.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/urllib/request.py", line 1344, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 1319, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 1365, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 1314, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 1074, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 1018, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 1460, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 455, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 1046, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 1317, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/python/project1/seaborn1.py", line 8, in <module>
    tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/apple/python/python-venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/seaborn/utils.py", line 595, in load_dataset
    if name not in get_dataset_names():
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/apple/python/python-venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/seaborn/utils.py", line 522, in get_dataset_names
    with urlopen(DATASET_NAMES_URL) as resp:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/urllib/request.py", line 215, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 ...
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/urllib/request.py", line 492, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/urllib/request.py", line 1392, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/urllib/request.py", line 1347, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Suggestion: download the relevant dataset [here](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/blob/master/tips.csv).

Comment: [matplotlib and OSx](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/installing/index.html#osx-notes). _Unfortunately, the way Apple currently installs its own copies of NumPy, Scipy and Matplotlib means that these packages are difficult to upgrade...One convenient way to install Matplotlib with other useful Python software is to use the Anaconda Python scientific software collection_

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier. All packages are installed as precompiled binaries. [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/). **If you are using Anaconda, do not use `pip` to install/remove packages that exist within the `conda` ecosystem.** Use `conda install package`. Only use `pip` if the package is not available with `conda install`. Using `pip` can potentially wreck your installation because `pip` and `conda` do not manage dependencies in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to spotlight(search bar) and search for `"Install Certificates.command"` then hit enter.

Or

`Macintosh HD-> Applications-> Python3.12 -> double click "Install Certificates.command"` file

[image]

Comment: Thanks - That fixed the errors. Now, when I run my python script it runs but I don't see anything. I've run this in both cmdline and PyCharm and get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: Your network stack installation lacks essential root certificates.

Your call to `sns.load_dataset("tips")`
tried to access a CSV under https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data , specifically
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/tips.csv

And without a DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1 certificate, that won't go smoothly.

---

If you use venv, conda, or poetry to obtain cPython + libraries,
this will all go very smoothly without you having to give it a moment's thought.

Comment: I followed the instructions at [https://seaborn.pydata.org/installing.html] and ran "pip install seaborn". If you are saying this is the wrong way or there is a better way then why is "pip install seaborn" even listed? So, I did as stated in the installation guide and it did not work. There was no mention of having to install certificates in the install guide, and if this is necessary then a note needs adding. After doing this I then see nothing when running. This is a typical user experience from a fresh install.